# Show input keystrokes in Vim

Tags: linux, vim

When I installed Vim on Windows, it (specifically gVim) used to show to show me the keystrokes I am currently entering in the bottom right corner of the screen.

But now I'm working with gVim on Linux, and it doesn't show me.

Is there a setting (`:set`) I need to turn on to do this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The option you're looking for is `showcmd`.